# Oval on JPanel won't draw on different locations

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have a panel on which I have to draw balls, each time I press the mouse button. The balls are supposed to be drawn on the location pressed by the mouse.

The balls are drawn just fine, however they are drawn on the same location every time, so unless I "move" the window right and left, the drawn balls would not be seen.

Here's my code:

### `GUIBalls`

```
public class GUIBalls {
public  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Balls");
public  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
private ArrayList<Ball> b = new ArrayList<>();
private Random rnd = new Random();

public GUIBalls(){
    setFrame();
    //moveBalls();
}
public void setFrame(){
    this.frame.setBounds(0,0,400,400);
    this.frame.add(panel);
    panel.setBounds(0,0,400,400);
    this.panel.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();
            createBalls(x,y);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });
}
public void createBalls(int x, int y){
    Ball ball = new Ball(x,y,10,10);
    this.b.add(ball);
    ball.draw(panel);
    panel.repaint();
}
}
```

### `Ball`

```
public class Ball extends JPanel {
int x;
int y;
int z;
int w;

public Ball(int x, int y, int z, int w) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    this.w = w;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.fillOval(0, 0, z, w);

}

public void draw(JPanel panel) {
    panel.add(this);
    panel.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

For some odd reason, the balls are not being drawn on different locations.

Pictures of what happens are attached.
[image]
[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: You're using `g.fillOval(0, 0, z, w);` which means that you're always drawing the oval at `x` position `0` and `y` position `0`.

Comment: @Titus I see. The problem is that when I change the 0 and 0 to something else, the ball donesn't draw at all.

Comment: The are drawn but they are most probably drawn outside the `Ball` `JPanel`'s visible area.

Comment: @Titus Thank you. How do I fix that?

Comment: Instead of creating new `JPanel`s on which you draw the ovals you should probably draw them directly on the `panel` `JPanel`.

Comment: @Titus you mean that the problem is the method public void draw(JPanel panel) ?

Comment: I mean that you can't really do it like you're trying to do it now. As it is now, you'll have to add the `Ball` `JPanel`s to the `panel` at specific locations which is not that easy.

Comment: Instead of that, you can easily draw ovals on the `panel` at specific locations.

Comment: @Titus Thank you, but I have to answer the question as I was told :-) The question was to draw them where the mouse clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code right now is that you have a combination of trying to do `custom painting` and trying to create a `custom component`. You need to decide which approach you want to use.

For the basics of custom painting read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) that has a working example showing how to do this. Well, it shows how to draw a square on a panel but you get the idea.

If you want to keep adding objects to be painted, then you need to keep your objects in a ArrayList and then in the paintComponent() method you iterate through the List to paint each object. This approach is demonstrated in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/).

If you want to create a Ball as a component, then you need to make sure you override the get preferred size to return the size of the Ball. Then you always draw the oval at offset (0, 0) of the panel. You then add the Ball component to the parent panel which uses a null layout. Because you use a null layout you will position the Ball on the parent panel by using the `setLocation(...)` method. You will also need to use the `setSize()` method of the Ball component to be the preferred size.

Comment: Thank you for the great post! I will read your links carefully.